# How to get Information about an element without a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have different container that get reloaded on different events. I have plenty of them, so I gave each container the class `load`.

This is how all of them look like:

```
<div class="load" data-href="facebook">
</div>
```

I also have a function, that is triggered by various actions:

```
function get_timing(time)
{
   $(".load").load("myfolder/mod_"+$(this).attr("data-href")+".php?action="+time, function() { 
       alert('Here I could use this:' + $(this).attr("data-href"));
   }
}
```

I know that I cannot use `this` in the example above, I could only use it in the callback. My question is: How can I use attributes of the object to define the path of the load function.

This is how it could work:

```
function get_timing(time)
{
   $(".load").fadeIn(10, function()
       {
           $(this).load("myfolder/mod_"+$(this).attr("data-href")+".php?action="+time, function() { 
           alert('loaded');
       }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without the asynchronus function (in this case `.fadIn`) around)

Hope I could explain my problem - thank you in advance!

Comment: Give them an ID and use $('#yourID')?

Comment: like I mentioned below - everycontainer would have a different ID and I would have to write the function for each container individually!

Comment: When you say, 'triggered by various actions', what are these actions? Can you not pass `$(this)` into your function from those actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go along with classes you can reference them via an index:

```
var element = $(".load").get(0);
console.log($(element).attr("data-href"));
```

Note that you have to re-jQueryfy `element` via `$(element)` in order to access `attr()`

If you want to read out all elements with a given class I recommend [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
//$.each($(".load"), function(index, value){
$(".load").each(function(index, value){
    console.log( $(value).attr("data-href"));   
});
```

Comment: I just edited my question - but I think the each function is the way to go -> I'll try it out and give you my feedback (+acceptance and +1 if its right!)

Comment: Why not `$(".load").each(function() {...});` ?

Comment: Because `$.each()` ranks higher in Google :3 Seriously I agree to you @FelixKling. It's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your container an id:

```
<div class="load" data-href="facebook" id="facebookcontainer">
</div>
```

Then instead of using this, you can use `$("#facebookcontainer")` in your javascript.

Comment: But that won't solve my problem - because I have an undefined number of divs. means that I have 10 with `data-href="facebook"` and maybe 20 with `data-href="twitter"` - I want to load them all with one function! And I don't like to give two elements the same ID.